# How to prevent infinite loop when moving dead-queue messages back to the main queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a dead-letter queue with failed messages with requeue=false.
I'm programmatically moving messages from the dead-queue back to the main queue by `RabbitOperations.receiveAndConvert(failedQueueName)` and `RabbitOperations.convertAndSend(msg)`. Is there a way to prevent a infinite loop without using a temp queue to hold my dead-queue messages before moving it to the main queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Deal-Leterring](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) in RabbitMQ adds `x-death` header:

> This array contains an entry for each dead lettering event, identified by a pair of `{queue, reason}`.

This one has a `count` field:

> how many times this message was dead-lettered in this queue for this reason

So, I'm sure you can add a `filtering` to your Dead-Letter queue consumer to drop messages which has undesired `count` already.